# Adb restoration stopped on Zenfone 3

Tags: adb, lineageos, asus-zenfone-3

My goal is to backup save data of two games from my older phone, which I succeeded, and to restore them to my new phone where I have Lineage 16.0 installed.

I used the command : `adb backup -apk nameoftheapp.com` and then `adb restore backup.ab`

But as soon as I type the second command and enter the backup password on the new telephone a dialog appears with "Restoration ended".

Is there a workaround/a way to troubleshoot the issue?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: leave the password empty on creating and restoring (this will disable backup encryption and reduce possible reasons for the fail). please read other questions in the Related section